# Want to send request from visitor's IP not from my VPS IP using python code

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to run a Python code to display the top 10 Google search results from my webpage. So whenever any visitor comes to my website's home page
& press the show results button it will run the Python code & display the results. My website is hosted on a VPS server. Now I want to
send the request to Google from the visitor IP not from my VPS IP(if from my VPS IP then Google will ban my IP as so many requests will
come from my VPS IP). How to implement this feature so that requests will go only from the visitor's IP.

The basic
code I will try:

```
from googlesearch import search


def get_user_query():
    return input("What do you want to search on Google? ")


def google_search(query):
    top_results = list(search(query, num_results=10))


    print(f"\nTop 10 results for '{query}':\n")
    for idx, result in enumerate(top_results, start=1):
        print(f"{idx}. {result}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_query = get_user_query()
    google_search(user_query)
```